# How to force Excel to open hyperlinks in IE (non-default browser)

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, internet-explorer, macros, hyperlink

I have a column of links that were concatenated (site url+specific ID number) and I would like to open them in IE because that is the only place the links open in (the site is a company tool). Is there a macro code I can use that will apply to all links in that column (considering each link will have its own ID number).

For reference, I have windows 10, working on an MS EXCEL for Microsoft 365 (64-bit)

Answer (score -1):

Refer to this article about VBA-Excel: Launch Internet Explorer (IE) using Microsoft Excel:

https://excel-macro.tutorialhorizon.com/vba-excel-launch-internet-explorer-ie-using-microsoft-excel/